# How to contain an object and call its method in a class?

Tags: python

I have two classes (`ClassA` and `ClassB`) and `ClassA` contains one object, `b`, that is an instance of `ClassB`. The question is that I can't call the `b`'s method in `Class A`.

```
class ClassB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class B init ...')

    def show(self):
        print('Showing class b')

class ClassA(object):
    #__classb = ClassB()
    def __init__(self, classb):
        print('Class A init ...')
        __classb = classb

    def show(self):
        __classb.show() # <=== I just want to do this!

b = ClassB()
a = ClassA(b)
a.show()
```

I expect the result should be:

```
Class B init ...
Class A init ...
Showing class b
```

But I meet the problem as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llSTk.png) shows:

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

By doing `__classb = classb` you are only defining a local `__classb` variable in the `__init__` method.

If you want `__classb` to be an instance attribute you will need to use `self`:

```
self.__classb = classb
```

And then:

```
def show(self):
    self.__classb.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a attribute for a instance of class B in class A like that self.__classb.
Following code

```
    class ClassB(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print('Class B init ...')

        def show(self):
            print('Showing class b')


    class ClassA(object):
        def __init__(self, classb):
            print('Class A init ...')
            self.__classb = classb

        def show(self):
            self.__classb.show()  # <=== I just want to do this!

b = ClassB()
a = ClassA(b)
a.show()
```